# CSS hover - parents are affected, too. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML (i am using one nice Tree class from SO, for listing categories):

```
<ul id="sidebar-menu" class="treeview">
<li class=" active"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/about-this-resource" cat_id="2" class="leaf">About this resource</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/what-is-podiatry" cat_id="3" class="leaf">What is podiatry?</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/how-can-a-podiatrist-help" cat_id="4" class="leaf">How can a podiatrist help?</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/when-you-should-consult-a-podiatrist" cat_id="5" class="leaf">When you should consult a podiatrist</a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Foot terminology</span><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/introduction" cat_id="7" class="leaf">Introduction</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/bones" cat_id="8" class="leaf">Bones</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/joints" cat_id="9" class="leaf">Joints</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/muscles" cat_id="10" class="leaf">Muscles</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/tendons-and-ligaments" cat_id="11" class="leaf">Tendons and Ligaments</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Foot problems</span><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/categories-of-foot-problem" cat_id="13" class="leaf">Categories of foot problem</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/the-most-common-foot-problems" cat_id="14" class="leaf">The most common foot problems</a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Achilles problems</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/the-achilles-tendon" cat_id="16" class="leaf">The Achilles tendon</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/achilles-tendon-xanthomas " cat_id="17" class="leaf">Achilles tendon xanthomas</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/achilles-tendonitis" cat_id="18" class="leaf">Achilles tendonitis</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/peroneal-tendon-issues" cat_id="19" class="leaf">Peroneal tendon issues</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Ankle problems</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/sprained-ankle" cat_id="27" class="leaf">Sprained ankle</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/osteochondritis" cat_id="28" class="leaf">Osteochondritis</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Ball and arch problems</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/over-pronation" cat_id="29" class="leaf">Over-pronation</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/metatarsalgia" cat_id="30" class="leaf">Metatarsalgia</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/plantar-fibromas" cat_id="31" class="leaf">Plantar fibromas</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/sesamoiditis" cat_id="32" class="leaf">Sesamoiditis</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/inflamed-ligaments" cat_id="33" class="leaf">Inflamed ligaments</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Common injuries</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/breaks" cat_id="34" class="leaf">Breaks</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/sprains" cat_id="35" class="leaf">Sprains</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/fractures" cat_id="36" class="leaf">Fractures</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/stiffness" cat_id="37" class="leaf">Stiffness</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/osteochondromas" cat_id="38" class="leaf">Osteochondromas</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/shin-splints" cat_id="39" class="leaf">Shin splints</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Deformities</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/bunions" cat_id="40" class="leaf">Bunions</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Foot diseases</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/arthritis" cat_id="41" class="leaf">Arthritis</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* menu */
#sidebar-menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:40px 0 40px 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#sidebar-menu li {
    line-height:32px;

    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#sidebar-menu li a, #sidebar-menu li span {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-left:43px;
    width:100%;
display:block;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul {
    list-style-type:none;
display:none;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0!important;
}
/*#sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul li {
    padding:0 0 0 0px!important;
}*/

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul li a, #sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul li span {
    padding-left:58px;
}

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub {
    position:relative;
}

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub.triangle-down::after{
content:"";
 width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    margin:15px 0 0 10px;
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 5px solid #666;
    position:absolute;
    left:280px;
    top:0px;

}
#sidebar-menu li.has-sub.triangle-up::after {
    content:"";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    margin:15px 0 0 10px;
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666;
    position:absolute;
    left:280px;
    top:0px;
}

#sidebar-menu li.active {
    background-image:url("http://bybyweb.com/infobase/images/triangle.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;


}
#sidebar-menu li:hover {
    background-image:url("http://bybyweb.com/infobase/images/triangle.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;


}
#sidebar-menu li:hover a {
    color:#454545!important;
}

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub:hover span {
    color:#454545!important;
}

#sidebar-menu li.active a {
    color:#454545!important;
}
.indent {
    padding-left:36px!important;


}
.indent a {
        font-size:14px!important;
}

/* menu */
```

Most relevant CSS for this problem is:

```
#sidebar-menu li:hover {
    background-image:url(../images/triangle.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;


}
```

Desired behavior: Show green highlight when menu item (li) is hovered, and that is partially done. BUT, as you can see, there are some nested lists (parent-child-grandchild... structure), and, when one 'grandchild' is hovered it affects parents too. It will be more clear if you check DEMO:
**http://jsfiddle.net/sdsptfL7/3/**

To recreate problem (actually, i think it is FEATURE, but my client doesn't think so:)) Click on 'Foot problems', 'Common injuries', and, hover over items in that, last level... You will notice that parent li's are also affected...

So, my question is how to avoid it? How to show highlight on JUST one item (and remove highlight from parents). I am opened to JQuery solution too (my miserable try is commented out in demo).

P.S. I can't change HTML structure, and after all, i think it is pretty good, 'normal', not sure about better solution... more or less classic 'nested lists' menu...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean BUT you can select only direct children with ul > li and only great grandchildren with something like ul li ul li... Have you tried these css selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `#sidebar-menu li:hover` to `#sidebar-menu li a:hover, #sidebar-menu li span:hover`. This will remove the effect from the list item and apply it to the child elements you are currently using.

Alternatively, you can use `#sidebar-menu li *:first-child:hover` if you cannot guarantee the child element will be an anchor or span element. [Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sdsptfL7/6/)

**Edit: Added snippet and [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sdsptfL7/5/).**

```js
$( "li.has-sub" ).click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
  $( this ).children('ul:first').stop().slideToggle(1000);
  //$(this).toggleClass('triangle-down','triangle-up');
});

$( "li.has-sub" ).hover(
  function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
    $( this ).addClass('triangle-down');
  }, function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
    $( this ).removeClass('triangle-down');
  }
);

/*$("#sidebar-menu li:not(.active)").hover(function(e) {
 
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://bybyweb.com/infobase/images/triangle.png)');
},
function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
}
 
);*/
```

```css
#left-sidebar {
 width:332px;
 background-color:#61bfee;
 
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display:table-cell;
}

/* menu */
#sidebar-menu {
 margin:0;
 padding:40px 0 40px 0;
 list-style-type:none;
}
#sidebar-menu li {
 line-height:32px;
 
 padding:0px;
 width:100%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
#sidebar-menu li a, #sidebar-menu li span {
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:15px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding-left:43px;
 width:100%;
display:block;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul {
 list-style-type:none;
display:none;
 padding:0!important;
 margin:0!important;
}
/*#sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul li {
 padding:0 0 0 0px!important;
}*/

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul li a, #sidebar-menu li.has-sub ul li span {
 padding-left:58px;
}

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub {
 position:relative;
}

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub.triangle-down::after{
content:"";
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 margin:15px 0 0 10px;
 padding:15px 0 0 0;
 border-top: 5px solid #666;
 position:absolute;
 left:280px;
 top:0px;
 
}
#sidebar-menu li.has-sub.triangle-up::after {
 content:"";
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 margin:15px 0 0 10px;
 padding:15px 0 0 0;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #666;
 position:absolute;
 left:280px;
 top:0px;
}

#sidebar-menu li.active {
 background-image:url("http://bybyweb.com/infobase/images/triangle.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;

 
}
/* change #sidebar-menu li:hover to */ #sidebar-menu li a:hover, #sidebar-menu li span:hover {
 background-image:url("http://bybyweb.com/infobase/images/triangle.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;

 
}
#sidebar-menu li:hover a {
 color:#454545!important;
}

#sidebar-menu li.has-sub:hover span {
 color:#454545!important;
}

#sidebar-menu li.active a {
 color:#454545!important;
}
/* Change .indent to */ .indent a {
 padding-left:/*change 36px to */ 72px !important;
}
.indent a {
  font-size:14px!important;
}

/* menu */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-sidebar">

<ul id="sidebar-menu" class="treeview">
<li class=" active"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/about-this-resource" cat_id="2" class="leaf">About this resource</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/what-is-podiatry" cat_id="3" class="leaf">What is podiatry?</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/how-can-a-podiatrist-help" cat_id="4" class="leaf">How can a podiatrist help?</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/when-you-should-consult-a-podiatrist" cat_id="5" class="leaf">When you should consult a podiatrist</a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Foot terminology</span><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/introduction" cat_id="7" class="leaf">Introduction</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/bones" cat_id="8" class="leaf">Bones</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/joints" cat_id="9" class="leaf">Joints</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/muscles" cat_id="10" class="leaf">Muscles</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/tendons-and-ligaments" cat_id="11" class="leaf">Tendons and Ligaments</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Foot problems</span><ul><li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/categories-of-foot-problem" cat_id="13" class="leaf">Categories of foot problem</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/the-most-common-foot-problems" cat_id="14" class="leaf">The most common foot problems</a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Achilles problems</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/the-achilles-tendon" cat_id="16" class="leaf">The Achilles tendon</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/achilles-tendon-xanthomas " cat_id="17" class="leaf">Achilles tendon xanthomas</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/achilles-tendonitis" cat_id="18" class="leaf">Achilles tendonitis</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/peroneal-tendon-issues" cat_id="19" class="leaf">Peroneal tendon issues</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Ankle problems</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/sprained-ankle" cat_id="27" class="leaf">Sprained ankle</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/osteochondritis" cat_id="28" class="leaf">Osteochondritis</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Ball and arch problems</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/over-pronation" cat_id="29" class="leaf">Over-pronation</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/metatarsalgia" cat_id="30" class="leaf">Metatarsalgia</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/plantar-fibromas" cat_id="31" class="leaf">Plantar fibromas</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/sesamoiditis" cat_id="32" class="leaf">Sesamoiditis</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/inflamed-ligaments" cat_id="33" class="leaf">Inflamed ligaments</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Common injuries</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/breaks" cat_id="34" class="leaf">Breaks</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/sprains" cat_id="35" class="leaf">Sprains</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/fractures" cat_id="36" class="leaf">Fractures</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/stiffness" cat_id="37" class="leaf">Stiffness</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/osteochondromas" cat_id="38" class="leaf">Osteochondromas</a></li>
<li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/shin-splints" cat_id="39" class="leaf">Shin splints</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Deformities</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/bunions" cat_id="40" class="leaf">Bunions</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="has-sub"><span>Foot diseases</span><ul><li class=" indent"><a href="http://localhost/infobase/article/1/arthritis" cat_id="41" class="leaf">Arthritis</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
    <div>
```

Comment: Almost perfect, thanks! Now i just have to find way to move highlight more left... (because of padding on last level elements, whole background/highlight isn't visible).

Comment: Change `.indent {padding-left: 36px !important;}` to `.indent a {padding-left: 72px /*or what is desired*/ !important;}`. I updated the snippet.